# imagemagick export jpg / png appearing inverted

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

I am using the **imagemagick** library to create a png or jpg from 2 images. The jpg / png is creating fine but one of the layered images appear inverted. It should have a white background but instead has black.

I have an uploader script which resizes the image and saves to an upload folder:

```
$maxsizeHeight=113; // MAX HEIGHT

        // create new Imagick object
        $image = new Imagick($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

        // RESIZES WIDTH TO MATCH HEIGHT OF 100
        $image->resizeImage(0,$maxsizeHeight,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);

        // Set to use jpeg compression
        $image->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
        // Set compression level (1 lowest quality, 100 highest quality)
        $image->setImageCompressionQuality(75);
        // Strip out unneeded meta data
        $image->stripImage();
        // Writes resultant image to output directory
        $image->writeImage($target_file);
        // Destroys Imagick object, freeing allocated resources in the process
        $image->destroy();
```

Then the second part i combine with a background image:

```
exec("convert $backgroundimg -interline-spacing 4 -font 'arial' -fill black -pointsize 16 -annotate +220+520 \"$newtext \" null: $logoPath -geometry +$POS_x+$POS_y -layers composite -layers optimize $save_file");
```

However, i get the following:

[image]

Comment: `fill black` ??? ofcourse it will be black..

Comment: @SubinThomas thats the text which appears elsewhere.  "... -font 'arial' -fill black -pointsize 16 ..."